# How to shorten the XML tag addressing by name taken from a map?

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-parsing

I am writing a function that creates a file from some XML. Depending on a parameter `dataSort` different tags can be taken as source data. Here is a small example code that outputs "Success" if it works. It does in THIS variant. Use this code for testing.

```
abstract class MessageData {
    static enum DataSort{REQUEST,RESPONSE}
    static Map<DataSort,String> xmlTag = [REQUEST:'input_parameters', RESPONSE:'output_parameters']

    static void exportSimulator(){
        DataSort dataSort= DataSort.REQUEST
        Node rootNode = new XmlParser().parseText(
"""     
<root>
    <api> 
        <input_parameters> 
            Success
        </input_parameters>
    </api>
</root>
""")
        String tag = xmlTag["$dataSort"]
        def field = rootNode.api."$tag"
        println field.text()
    }
}
```

I would like to write the two last lines as one. If I'll write
`"$xmlTag["$dataSort"]"`,
Groovy after the first parsing will interpret it as `"$xmlTag[REQUEST]"` and this map addresation will find `null` and the result is empty.  If I'll write
`"$xmlTag[$dataSort]"`,
really I do not know how it will be parsed, but it gives `null`, too.

Can I get the variable tag directly from the map here?

BTW, I would be grateful for any advice about some better source about Groovy parsing.

---

#### Edit:

The following is for correct search only:

The problem was not in parsing, but in

## bad map initiation by enum constants

Comment: Do you have a simple runnable example?

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42222531/groovy-xmlslurper-searching-sepecific-node/42229427#42229427) - `xml.'**'.find{it.name()== element}` ?

Comment: Oh, I see, I'll make it in ten minutes.

Comment: @Rao yes, but that won't work, reports java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'parameter' on null object. I.e. it finds nothing.

Comment: Please show your xml snippet and what data needs to be extracted.

Comment: @Rao I have changed the code to a runnable snippet.

Comment: @tim_yates  I have changed the code to a runnable snippet.

Comment: @Gangnus, thank you for the edit, please check the answer and see if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you can do it, but have to use it between `"${..}"`, as given below:

```
rootNode.api."${xmlTag[dataSort]}"
```

Here is the entire script to be able to test standalone and comments in-line where applicable:

```
enum DataSort{REQUEST,RESPONSE}
//Need to use key in between (..) as REQUEST, RESPONSE are not string literals in here
Map<DataSort,String> xmlTag = [(DataSort.REQUEST):'input_parameters', (DataSort.RESPONSE):'output_parameters']

def exportSimulator = { 
        DataSort dataSort= DataSort.REQUEST
        //Used slurper
        def rootNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText(
"""     
<root>
    <api> 
        <input_parameters> 
            Success
        </input_parameters>
    </api>
</root>
""")
        //Here is the main change that you are interested in
        def field = rootNode.api."${xmlTag[dataSort]}"
        println field.text().trim()
}
​exportSimulator()​
```

You can quickly try it online <kbd>[Demo](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5071332966400000)</kbd>

Below two statements yields the same result:

```
def field = rootNode.api."${xmlTag[dataSort]}"

def field = rootNode.'**'.find{it.name() == xmlTag[dataSort] }
```

Comment: Thank you. As usually, the error was in another place. But I didn't expected that that initiation of map using enums is so awkward in Groovy.

Comment: Hope the above resolves the issue. Isn't it or still l looking for something more?

Comment: Without any doubt. I only added some info for search bots, for this post to be correctly found, and it took a bit time. And I upvoted you so late. Sorry

Comment: No problem. You could see about the same in the above code and comments.